# How come the universe is considered flat if zero point energy is infinite?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, curvature, vacuum, cosmological-constant

If quantum field theory calculates that the vacuum energy is infinite and Einstein's theory of gravity implies this energy should produce a curvature of space-time then why shouldn't the universe be round and expanding like a balloon instead of predicted flat? Couldn't it just be we observe it is flat because we are only seeing a minute part of it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem

Comment: The lidea of the zero point energy in QFT is based on the fact that the lowest energy of a quantum oscillator is not zero. This however is true only on one condition - the oscillator must physically exist. The lowest energy of a quantum oscillator that does not physically exist is zero.

Comment: renormalization > poppycock as superstring theory or does the graviton have a partner?